# How to get the custom class added to a view

Tags: 7, views, theming

Views let people to add custom css class to a display. I'm looking to get this information and add to the body tag.

I try with this two functions and the dpm() function from devel:

```
views_get_view('name');
views_get_page_view();
```

But I'm not able to find the custom class that I add to the view.

Do you have any idea how to get this information?

Comment: If you found the answer, please write it as answer. Questions and answers needs to be separated, since this is a Q&A site.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to get this information, you can use [template_preprocess_views_view](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/theme!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_views_view/7)

```
/**
 * Preprocess the primary theme implementation for a view.
 */
function YOURTHEME_preprocess_views_view(&$vars) {
  $view = $vars['view'];
  switch ($view->name) {
    case 'your_view_name' :
      // print out the array with all options to see what you're dealing with
      drupal_set_message('<pre>' . print_r($view->display['display_name']->display_options, true) . '</pre>');
      break;
  }
}
```

But if you will need to override this custom class, you'll need to use [hook_views_pre_render()](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_render/7)

```
function YOURTHEME_views_pre_render(&$view) {

  switch ($view->name) {
    case 'name_of_your_view' :

      // override the view settings
      // for example: $view->field['fieldname']->options['label'] = 'Some label';

      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry jack-Pl, I don't explain fine, I want to add the new css class to the body html tag. So I need to load the view within the hook_preprocess_html().

Comment: no problem, I'll edit this, but if you have the view object within hook_preprocess_html() and all information is there, so where is the issue?

Comment: I don't realize about the information in hook_preprocess_html. I'm going to check it.